# Incorrect Node version for Angular 14

Tags: node.js, angular, linux

I am upgrading my angular app to 14 and facing some issues with the node on Ubantu 22.04 system.

node -v gives me v16.20.1
but yarn start says :

Node.js version v12.22.12 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.15, or v16.10.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

Why does it say that when I already have node 16 ?

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
"@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
"@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/service-worker": "^14.3.0",
"@apollo/client": "3.6.9",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.1.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^14.3.3",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^14.3.3",
"@ngrx/store": "^14.3.3",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "14.3.3",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.0.2",
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.1",
"apollo-angular": "3.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3",
"express": "^4.15.2",
"graphql": "^16",
"html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
"i18next": "^21.10.0",
"i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.5",
"jquery": "^3.6.3",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"ng-recaptcha": "^9.0.0",
"ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
"ngx-alerts": "^10.1.3",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^14.0.1",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^14.0.1",
"ngx-pagination": "5.1.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
"ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},

 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "^14.2.11",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "12.7.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.7.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.7.0",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.7.0",
"@angular/cli": "^14.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
"@angular/localize": "14.3.0",
"@ngrx/schematics": "^14.3.3",
"@nguniversal/builders": "^12.1.0",
"@types/express": "^4.17.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
"eslint": "^7.26.0",
"eslint-plugin-deprecation": "1.3.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"karma": "~6.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
"postcss-scss": "4.0.4",
"stylelint": "^14.10.0",
"stylelint-config-standard": "^27.0.0",
"stylelint-order": "^5.0.0",
"stylelint-scss": "^4.3.0",
"typescript": "4.8.2"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your `package.json`?

Comment: I edited the question with package.json

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using nvm to manage your node versions?

Comment: I am not sure. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Digit "nvm list" in the terminal, but it is a tool you need to explicitly to install, therefore, if you ask about it, probably you do not have it.

Comment: That is not the complete package.json. Do you maybe have an `engine` entry there?

Comment: @mbojko no there is no engine entry in package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to follow the following steps:

- Try to look for any previous node installation and remove it (if any)
- Check the yarn version and eventually update it, as it might enforce a node version related to its (yarn) version. It was in the past at least

Comment: yarn was causing the problem. I upgraded to yarn v1.22.19 and that fixed it. Thanks for your help !! @Francesco